# Types of lists in sharepoint 2010

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation

I think there are two types of lists in Sharepoint. **Internal lists** and **external lists**. 
**External** lists means when we create any list by any of the templates like announcements, calender,Custom list etc. 
Then what are the **internal** lists in sharepont.
Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

External list refers to Lists that have an external data source.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558778

And the internal list is a normal list in SharePoint.